# Make UpSet function display numbers above the bars

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using the `ComplexHeatmap` package to represent the intersection among different `GRanges`. The vignette has some nice example to plot it:

```
library(circlize)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(GenomicRanges)
lt2 = lapply(1:4, function(i) generateRandomBed())
lt2 = lapply(lt2, function(df) GRanges(seqnames = df[, 1], 
    ranges = IRanges(df[, 2], df[, 3])))
names(lt2) = letters[1:4]
m = make_comb_mat(lt2)
UpSet(m)
```

[image]

It is very handy. However, the `UpSet` function do not plot the intersection numbers above each bar such as the sister function `upset` in the `UpSetR` package:

```
library('UpSetR')
movies <- read.csv( system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), 
                    header=T, sep=";" )

require(ggplot2); require(plyr); require(gridExtra); require(grid);

upset(movies, 
      sets = c("Action", "Comedy", "Drama"), 
      order.by="degree", matrix.color="blue", point.size=5,
      sets.bar.color=c("maroon","blue","orange"))
```

[image]

The `upset` function do not allow the `m` object. Thus, I suppose I need to use `UpSet` in my case. However, could someone help me to get the correspondent number above the bars? I could not find a parameter to easily plot it or even how the internal functions define it. I would be grateful for any help.